# No e-commerce-tracking in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I switched e-commerce-tracking on and extended the standard-script created by Google
to check if it works:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-47398882-9', 'dummy.net');
ga('send', 'pageview');

ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': '34-57658',
    'affiliation': 'Dummy Shop',
    'revenue': 109.56,
    'shipping': 4.5,
    'tax': 19.81
});

ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': '34-57658',
    'name': 'Shirt Amalfi',
    'sku': 'WKM-76576-7867-s', 
    'category': '', 
    'price': 105.06,
    'quantity': 1
});

ga('send', 'ecommerce'); 
</script>
```

After calling the page that includes this script I would expect to see the data of
this dummy-order. But there is the page-view only. Is this the fault of the script or an analytics
configuration problem?

Isn't there a way to debug this beyond the browser? Some Google error reporting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ecommerce send call should be:

> ga('ecommerce:send');

Google documentation on [Ecommerce Tracking - Web Tracking (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce#sendingData)

Comment: I am facing issue while firing ecommerece event using tag manager, any idea to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

We can able to debug using chrome plugin.
 Install the plugin and refresh the page and click on the plugin icon then you can able to see the error and suggestions

Click here : [Tag Assistant (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en)

Install into your chrome

Enjoy coding  , all the best:-)